# How to displaying all data from all file_get_contents & search one of them

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

I have some txt files, and show only one file using the function file_get_contents ().

if I want to find an object within each file, then I have to open the file one by one and search it using ctrl + f.

I think it's not an effective way to search for an object from all the existing files.

Can anyone suggest me how to create a "search feature" to search for an object on some of the txt files?

i use php script.

[this is txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDaA3.png)

Comment: You have to use `scandir()` and put all result in an array. Put all path and crawl to it's sub of sub folders. After that you can find the file (with path) in that array.

Comment: can you give example code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a scandir to list files, then use file_get_contents to find the content and search into with

Comment: can you give example code ?

Comment: $q = "find_this";
$dir = "your_directory";
$files = scandir($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
 $sContent = file_get_contents($dir."/".$file);
 if (stripos($q,$sContent) !== false){
  echo $file."\n";
 }
}

Comment: Sorry, Inverse stripos parameters